# The system cannot find the file specified when trying to run vc_redist.x64 within nanoserver build using dockerfile

Tags: c++, docker, visual-c++, dockerfile, nano-server

I am trying to setup a nanoserver container in order to run a C++ executable that was built with the /MD flag in Visual Studio 2017.

I know I need to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017.

I managed to create the container, download the Redistributable and add it to the container at the root. however when build from the Dockerfile I get the following error message:

```
Exception(2) tid(360) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
        CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\ComputeSystemManager_ExecuteProcess\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
     Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; $verbosePreference='Continue'; Start-Process -filepath c:\\vc_redist.exe -ArgumentList \"/install\", \"/passive\", \"/norestart\", \"'/log a.txt'\" -PassThru | wait-process","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"PSCORE":"C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\pwsh.exe","ProgramFiles":"C:\\Program Files","VS2017":"https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
```

here is my Dockerfile:

```
ARG FROM_IMAGE=microsoft/powershell:6.0.0-beta.9-nanoserver-1709
FROM ${FROM_IMAGE}

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]


ARG VS2017=https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe
ADD ${VS2017} /vc_redist.exe

RUN Start-Process -filepath c:\vc_redist.exe -ArgumentList "/install", "/passive", "/norestart", "'/log a.txt'" -PassThru | wait-process
```

I tried removing last line from dockerfile and running it within the container after building I simply get no output.

also would like to avoid using windows server core as we are trying to keep the size as small as possible.

Any help greatly appreciated.